# How do I rename a tSQLt test class?

Tags: redgate, tsqlt

I'm developing a database using the [Red Gate SQL Developer](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/) tools. [SQL Test](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-test/), the SSMS add-in that runs tSQLt tests, lacks a way to rename test classes.

I have a test called `[BackendLayerCustomerAdministrationTests].[test uspMaintainCustomerPermissions throws error when PermissionValue is missing or empty]`.

The name is so long it [breaks Deployment Manager](http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=19309).

> 2013-12-05 18:48:40 +00:00 ERROR  The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

There are other unwieldly test names in this class, so I want to start by shortening the class name.

A more succinct class name would be `CustomerTests`.

[sp_rename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) is no help here.

```
EXECUTE sys.sp_rename
  @objname = N'BackendLayerCustomerAdministrationTests',
  @newname = N'CustomerTests';
```

> Msg 15225, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 374
>   No item by the name of 'BackendLayerCustomerAdministrationTests' could be found in the current database 'ApiServices', given that @itemtype was input as '(null)'.

How do I change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to come into this so late! I'm a developer who's working on SQL Test.

We've just added the ability to rename test classes to the latest version of SQL Test.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-test/

It's now as simple as right clicking on the context menu for a test class, or pressing **F2**:

[image]

Please bear in mind that this option will not appear for old versions of tSQLt. To upgrade, right click on the database to uninstall the framework, then do **Add database...** to re-add it (the right-most button in the window):

[image]

Alternatively, you could just call a new procedure in tSQLt called `tSQLt.RenameClass`, which is what SQL Test calls behind the scenes.

Please let us know if you have any issues with this!

David

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks, David! Never too late!

Answer (score 6):

tSQLt test classes are schemas with a special extended property.

Cade Roux's great solution for [renaming schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/317711/111424) is to create a new schema, transfer all the objects, then drop the old schema.

If we did that here we'd lose the extended property.

Let's adapt it for the tSQLt framework.

## How to rename a tSQLt test class

Create a new test class.

```
EXECUTE tSQLt.NewTestClass
  @ClassName = 'CustomerTests';
```

You should see the old class and the new class together in the `tSQLt.TestClasses` view.

```
SELECT *
FROM tSQLt.TestClasses;

 Name                                      SchemaId
----------------------------------------- ----------
 SQLCop                                           7
 BackendLayerCustomerAdministrationTests         10
 CustomerTests                                   14
```

Cade used Chris Shaffer's [select variable concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/194887/111424) trick to build a list of transfer statements, and print the result.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql +
N'ALTER SCHEMA CustomerTests
TRANSFER BackendLayerCustomerAdministrationTests.' + QUOTENAME(name) + N';' +
CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM sys.objects
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]) = N'BackendLayerCustomerAdministrationTests';

PRINT @sql;
```

Ugly, but effective.

Copy the output and execute as a new query.

```
ALTER SCHEMA CustomerTests
TRANSFER BackendLayerCustomerAdministrationTests.[test uspMaintainCustomer validate merged data];
ALTER SCHEMA CustomerTests
TRANSFER BackendLayerCustomerAdministrationTests.[test uspMaintainCustomerPermissions throws error when PermissionValue is missing or empty];
```

I've shown only two tests here, but it should work for all of them.

Now drop the old test class.

```
EXECUTE tSQLt.DropClass
  @ClassName = N'BackendLayerCustomerAdministrationTests';
```

The old class should be gone from view.

```
SELECT *
FROM tSQLt.TestClasses;

 Name                                      SchemaId
----------------------------------------- ----------
 SQLCop                                           7
 CustomerTests                                   14
```

Run all your tests again to check that it worked.

```
EXECUTE tSQLt.RunAll;

+----------------------+                                                       
|Test Execution Summary|                                                       
+----------------------+                                                       

|No|Test Case Name                                                              |Result |
+--+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|1|[CustomerTests].[test uspMaintainCustomer throws error on missing APIKey]   |Success|
|2|[CustomerTests].[test uspMaintainCustomerPermissions validate merged data]  |Success|
|3|[SQLCop].[test Decimal Size Problem]                                        |Success|
|4|[SQLCop].[test Procedures Named SP_]                                        |Success|
|5|[SQLCop].[test Procedures using dynamic SQL without sp_executesql]          |Success|
|6|[SQLCop].[test Procedures with @@Identity]                                  |Success|
|7|[SQLCop].[test Procedures With SET ROWCOUNT]                                |Success|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Case Summary: 7 test case(s) executed, 7 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 errored.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Success!

Answer (score 2):

What is your workflow like?  If you have all your tests for that test class in one script with exec tSQLt.NewTestClass 'BackendLayerCustomerAdministrationTests' then you can just find and replace the testclass name and you are done.

e.g.

```
EXEC tSQLt.DropClass 'BackendLayerCustomerAdministrationTests'
GO
EXEC tSQLt.NewTestClass 'CustomerTests'
GO

CREATE PROC [CustomerTests].[test_Insert_AddsACustomer]
AS
etc, etc
```

This will work because the EXEC tSQLt.NewTestClass 'CustomerTests' will drop all objects in the testclass and they will be recreated as the rest of the script runs.

Comment: In the Red Gate database model, you typically make changes to the database and then push them to source control. The format writes each object to its own file as CREATE statement, stores procedural transformations only in exceptional cases. SQL Compare can usually work out the dependencies automatically. Bad things can happen with careless edits of its generated scripts, so I try to discourage it. You could probably get away with search and replace on the source files and push back to the database with SQL Compare, but this seemed safer. What is your workflow like?

Comment: Thanks Iain.  It isn't immediately obvious from the question that the Red Gate tools are being used for the entire unit testing and source control workflow. I have integrated my tSQLt code into Visual Studio. Here is an example of the workflow that I use. https://github.com/chilli-andrew/tsqlt-demo-workflow

Comment: Your workflow looks like a mini [SQL Test](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-test/). Thanks for sharing it. As a student, I get all the Microsoft tools through Dreamspark, but can't afford my own license for the Red Gate tools. Next time I use SQL Server at home, I'll see what I can do with it.

Comment: Added my workflow context to the question. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I find that because the projects that I work on involve more than just database code, it makes sense to work in Visual Studio.  I use either git or svn as my source control and SSDT (database projects) or FluentMigarator to manage my database scripts.  I also have a T4 template to create an NUnit test wrapper around my tSQLt tests so that I can easily integrate my tSQLt test with my C# unit tests on the CI server.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest is probably:

```
EXEC tSQLt.RenameClass 'old test class name', 'new test class name';
```

See the [tSQLt docs for RenameClass](http://tsqlt.org/user-guide/test-creation-and-execution/renameclass/)

It seems Red-gate have added that ability to SQL Test since this question was posted, but the raw SQL code is somehow leaner and cleaner (whether or not you use the excellent SQL Test)